# Implementing refresh tokens in Xamarin (Authorization code flow - OAuth2)

Tags: c#, xamarin, oauth, identityserver4, refresh-token

Can anyone maybe share some tutorial, resources, link, anything related to implementing refresh tokens when using Xamarin.

What I am trying to accomplish is authentication code flow(where user firstly provides credentials to identity server, gets temporary code, which later gets exchanged for real access token, for accessing APIs).

I was looking all around, but nothing helped me. I have realized that implementing refresh tokens is not so easy in Xamarin, but still there must be a way.

I was trying something with `TokenClient()` class.

```
var client = new TokenClient("https://localhost:44305/connect/token", "mylegislature");

var request = await client.RequestResourceOwnerPasswordAsync(username, password);

if (!request.IsError)
{
     _secureService.StoreAuthToken(request);
}
```

And with `AuthorizeRequest()` class:

```
var authorizeRequest =
         new AuthorizeRequest("https://localhost:44305/connect/token");

var parameters = new Dictionary<string, string>();
            parameters.Add("response_type", "token");
            parameters.Add("client_id", "mylegislature");
            parameters.Add("scope", "MyLegislatureAPI");
            parameters.Add("redirect_uri", "https://localhost:44301/account/oAuth2");

var authorizeUri = authorizeRequest.Create(parameters);
```

But with non of them I have succeed in sending request to IdentityServer, which is ok since it is expecting respecting of authorization code flow of OAuth2, but I am unable to implement code in right way since I couldn't find any useful resources about this. If someone has something for sharing please help.

Comment: In general, asking for a tutorial is off topic for stack overflow. But you can find a nice guide for implementing refresh tokens in Xamarin [here](https://lostechies.com/jimmybogard/2014/11/13/mobile-authentication-with-xamarin-auth-and-refresh-tokens/).

Comment: Better yet, up to date Xamarin samples: https://github.com/IdentityModel/IdentityModel.OidcClient.Samples